# Unable to recieve notifications from Firebase. Unregistered registration token

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have setup Firebase in an Xamarin.Android application, following this guide:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/

It seemed to work at first, with receiving notifications without problems. Then I tried to update the code and redeploy to Device and afterwards nothing happened. Since I have been unable to receive any notifications from the Firebase Console.

I have tried

- Uninstall application and deploy again
- Download new google-service.json from Firebase Console
- Delete and setup new Firebase Project, and updating google-service.json for this

When the application is newly deployed, and I try to send a notification, nothing happens. After an update and redeploy I get the error "Unregistered registration token" in the console.

Before setting up a new Firebase Project I would get the following error when trying to subscribe to a topic
"INVALID_PARAMETERS", but this problem has seen to disappear after creating a new project. Now then subscribing to Topic, it appears in the Console after some time. But trying to send notifications to the topic, gives no results.

**Edit - Added code**

MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Label = "<<App Label>>", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private TextView msgText;
    private const string Tag = "MainActivity";
    private FirebaseAnalytics _analytics;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        _analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(this);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        msgText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.msgText);

        if (Intent.Extras != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
            {
                var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                Log.Debug(Tag, "Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, value);
            }
        }

        IsPlayServicesAvailable();

        var logTokenButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.logTokenButton);
        logTokenButton.Click += delegate {
            Log.Debug(Tag, "InstanceID token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token);
        };

        var subButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.subscribeButton);
        subButton.Click += SubButton_Click;
    }

    private void SubButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("A");
        Log.Debug(Tag, "Subscribed to A");
    }

    public bool IsPlayServicesAvailable()
    {
        int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.Success)
        {
            if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsUserResolvableError(resultCode))
                msgText.Text = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorString(resultCode);
            else
            {
                msgText.Text = "This device is not supported";
                Finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            msgText.Text = "Google Play Services is available.";
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

StwFirebaseInstanceIdService.cs

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new []{ "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class StwFirebaseInstanceIdService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    private const string Tag = "StwFirebaseInstanceIdService";
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        Log.Debug(Tag, "Refreshed Token: " + refreshedToken);
        //SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
    {

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="<<Package Name>>" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
<application android:label="<<App Label>>">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Hi Martin. Please post relevant code snippets. Along with a sample payload and the complete error logs.

Comment: Have you updated the token when you reinstall your app?

Comment: @AL. I have added code from my project in the original post.

Comment: @MikeMa Each time I reinstalled the app, I got a new token.

Comment: I mean did you update this token in Firebase console?

Comment: Each time I got a new token, I updated the device token in the Firebase console when sending a new notification

Comment: Your manifest is missing the `Internet` permission. Anyway, I'm facing the same problem for days now. I thing there must be a problem with the packages, some buggy recent update.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into the same issue. Try to uninstall the app one more time and before you get the token (old one), call the refresh token to get the refreshed token:

```
public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
    { // Your custom implementation depends on your server }
```

for more information visit [Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/)

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned tutorial is quite good but misses a few points.  I couldn't get it to work until I added my app's SHA1 key to the registration.  You can get this by the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\keytool.exe" -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

You might have to edit the command a bit to match your Java version.

The second thing is that that there seems to be some issues with DEBUG builds.  I got this method from somewhere (don't know where now).

```
        private void ConfigureFireBase()
        {
#if DEBUG
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var instanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
                instanceId.DeleteInstanceId();
                Android.Util.Log.Debug("TAG", "{0} {1}", instanceId?.Token?.ToString(), instanceId.GetToken(GetString(Resource.String.gcm_defaultSenderId), Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.InstanceIdScope));
            });

            // For debug mode only - will accept the HTTPS certificate of Test/Dev server, as the HTTPS certificate is invalid /not trusted
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
#endif
        }
```

Call it from OnCreate, just after OnCreate like so:

```
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        ConfigureFireBase();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging (71.1740.0) on Visual Studio for Mac (8.3.11).  Testing on older (API 21) and newer (API 28) physical android devices.

First deploy works, new tokens on both devices.  A custom REST API call to FCM successful:

```
{"multicast_id":4160565375891761047,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1576702929647400%320d8b4c320d8b4c"}]}
```

Changing code, and redeploying in Debug mode to the same devices works fine.  Sending from Firebase console works fine, notifications to both devices in same project app in FCM.

After some hours, the custom REST API returns for the older device token (no code change):

```
{"multicast_id":565695677811030352,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

Then after some more hours, the new device token also returns "NotRegistered" from the custom REST API (no code change).  Also, the Firebase console no longer sends notifications to devices.

The only way I got the custom REST API and Firebase console to correctly send notifications once this happens, is to use Visual Studio to manually remove the app from the device:

```
Visual Studio Menu > Build > Remove from Device
```

Deploying again will install the app as though it were new to the device, and request a fresh token.

Note: Already unchecked "Preserve data/cache between application deploys" in the Visual Studio preferences, with no significant change.  Clearing the app's data/cache doesn't work either.

Used latest Microsoft code from GitHub (Dec 2019): https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/tree/master/samples/com.google.firebase/firebase-messaging